# "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode" error in pickle load

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, pickle

I am trying to save an array of Tweet objects in file. Tweet class instances contain utf8 encoding characters. you can see the code below:

```
class Tweet:
    author='';
    text='';
    time='';
    date='';
    timestamp='';

with open('tweets.dat','wb') as f:
     pickle.dump(all_tweets,f)

with open('tweets.dat') as f:
   all_tweets = pickle.load(f)
```

When I run the code, it returns an exception on *pickle.load(f)* line stating that :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 25: character maps to <undefined>
```

My machine specification:

> Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016,
>   11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Why do you write into the file in binary mode and read from it in text mode?

Comment: I want to retrieve my objects and then use them. Although I mentioned the simple case here, the Tweet class may contain non-textual attributes as well.

Comment: You replace whole `DAT` file on write but you want use it with external encoding/decoding system. Did you remember "which decoding used on creating this file ?" . Most answer "No idea !" , cos where `os_encoding`, `python encode`, `python decode` patterns ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Python 3, the pickle module expects the underlying file objects to accept or return **bytes**. You correctly open the file in binary mode for writing, but failed to do the same for reading. The read part should be:

```
with open('tweets.dat', 'rb') as f:
   all_tweets = pickle.load(f)
```

Ref: extract from the documentation of `pickle.load(fd)`:

> ...Thus file can be an on-disk file opened for binary reading, an io.BytesIO object, or any other custom object that meets this interface.

Comment: thank you. unfortunatly, it doesn't work. it returns another error "AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Tweet' on"

Comment: @CoderInNetwork: you should edit your question to add a [mcve]. I tested with a slightly modified object of what is currently shown in your question (using non ascii data) and it worked. Pickle is a well known and well tested module without knowing *exactly* how you use it, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: when using 'rb' mode for load(), strings are treated as bytes, and considering the size of data being unpickled, that could be a problem to convert these bytes back to strings

Comment: this, along with `pickle.load(f,encoding='latin1')` solved it for me